# Issue about jetty errorhandling

Tags: java, spring, jetty

I come across some issues when setting the error handler to jetty:

I create my own error handler:

```java
public class ServerErrorPageErrorHandler extends ErrorPageErrorHandler {
    @Override
    protected void writeErrorPageBody(HttpServletRequest request, Writer writer, int code, String message, boolean showStacks)
            throws IOException {
     String uri= request.getRequestURI();

     writeErrorPageMessage(request,writer,code,message,uri);
     if (showStacks)
        writeErrorPageStacks(request,writer);
        writer.write("<hr><i><small>Powered by OWN-SERVER://</small></i><hr/>\n");
    }
}
```

And set it in the file 'jett-web.xml' which is in the folder '/webapp/WEB-INF/'

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<Set name="contextPath">/</Set>

<Set name="errorHandler">
    <New class="com.mobile.service.handlers.ServerErrorPageErrorHandler"/>
</Set></Configure>
```

when jetty is started, it said no such method for setErrorHandler for class WebAppContext,(I found setErrorHandler method in the its parent class ErrorHandler, so I think it does mean that)

And then create a file 'error-handler-context.xml' and fill in the file:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>   
  <Set name="errorHandler">
     <New class="com.mobile.service.handlers.ServerErrorPageErrorHandler"/>
   </Set> 
</Configure>
```

Then jetty is started successfully, but the error handler has not effect.

I just want to change the messages that show in the error pages "Power by jetty" to "Power by OWN SERVER".

And I do not want to create a new error page.

So how to realize it?

And I change the config file like this:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
      <Call name="setErrorHandler">
        <Arg>
            <New class="com.hp.mobile.service.handlers.ServerErrorPageErrorHandler"/>
       </Arg>
     </Call>

</Configure>
```

After jetty started, it still says NoSuchMethod 'setErrorHanlder' exception,

And I debug it, and get the exception:

> "java.lang.illegalargumentexception: argument type mismatch"
>   at the method.invoke(obj, arg) in "TypeUtil.java“

setErrorHandler's argument is the `ErrorHandler` class,

And in my case, it extends from the `ErrorHandler`,

So why does it happen?

BTW: I also change the class `ServerErrorPageErrorHandler` to extend from `ErrorHandler`, it does not work also.